# Not expanding NSScroller

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsscroller

The `NSScroller` automatically expands it's width when the user hovers over it.

[image]

However, the document view has pretty little space, and this is why the scroller should not expand.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a little too late, but something like this might help?

1) Create custom scroller for your vertical scrollbar.

2) Override -*drawKnob* to force draw knob the default size even when it is to be drawn 'expanded'.

```
-(void)drawKnob
{
    NSRect knobSlot = [self rectForPart:NSScrollerKnob];
    if(sFlags.isHoriz)
    {
        knobSlot.size.height = 9;
        knobSlot.origin.y = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        knobSlot.size.width  = 9;
        knobSlot.origin.x = 6;
    }

    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:knobSlot xRadius:5 yRadius:5];

    [[NSColor scrollBarColor] set];
    [path fill];
}
```

3) Depending on if you still want the knob slot or not, override -*drawKnobSlotInRect*:

```
-(void)drawKnobSlotInRect:(NSRect)slotRect highlight:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSRect newRect = slotRect;
    if(sFlags.isHoriz)
        newRect.origin.y = 4;
    else
        newRect.origin.x = 4;
    [super drawKnobSlotInRect:newRect highlight:flag];
}
```